# Render Deployment (Node module problems)

Tags: github, deployment, render

I'm pretty new in this. I'm currently trying to learn web development from an online course in Udemy (Colt's Steele) and I'm stuck in the deployment part of the app. I'm using render and it when I try to deploy, it just gives me this error.

[image]

Basically since I'm "scared" that I might break the deployment part, I copied all the files in my app folder and place it in a new one and made a repository on GitHub and then use render to deploy it. I don't know if I'm asking the right questions but here it is:

1.) If I copy all the files from the original app folder to a new one, do I need to install all dependencies first and then make a repository on GitHub and then try deploying it on render?

2.) When I got this error in render, Error: Cannot find module ‘/opt/render/project/src/app.js’ I read that I probably need to set my Root Directory which I did and it went live but gave me tons of error and if I click on my app link it would redirect me to a page showing Internal Service Error.

I tried researching the error from render but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, [please do not upload images of errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Can you elaborate on the errors you're getting after setting your Root Directory?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The file that is throwing the error cannot read the `src/app.js` module.

Check if its imported correctly, where the error is thrown

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).